# Как перерисовать индикатор в mql4?

Tags: mql

Есть советник в котором вызывается индикатор Скользящая средняя с помощью команды iMA. Соответственно на графике средняя отрисовывается. В определенные моменты меняется период МА и окно графика заполняется Средними с разными периодами. Как перерисовывать индикатор, т.е. при изменении периода удалять старую МА и рисовать новую?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию, указанную в справочнике:

```
void  HideTestIndicators( 
   bool hide // флаг сокрытия/показа индикатора
   );
```

Таким образом можно скрыть индикатор, перерисовать его и снова показать на графике.